# Does try catch have block level scope?

Tags: javascript

If i create a variable in the catch block, is this block level scope?

It seems to create it in the global scope.

I thought it was block level because don't transpilers convert let statement to try/catch?

```
try {
    throw Error("test");
} catch (e) {
    var x = 15;
    console.log(x);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: No, a `var` declaration in the `catch` clause is at function scope. You could use `let` however (in ES2015).

Comment: so there was never a hack to use block level variables before es6? I thought i watched a video about it.

Comment: Actually there is one special scoping rule for `catch()` - the "parameter" for the `catch` block is scoped to that block, almost like it were a function parameter.

Comment: Transpilers don't convert a let statement to try/catch block(s) (see: http://es6console.com/itmynbl7/ for an example). Modern transpilers do name analysis and rename variables to unbound names to 'simulate' block scoping.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Babel deals with `let` by creating distinctly-name variables with `var`. In other words, if you use "xyz" as a variable name in the same function in several different block scopes (via `let`), you'll have a bunch of variations of "xyz" as `var` variables in the Babel output.

Comment: Maybe I was thinking of the parameter of the catch block.

Comment: Yes the parameter of the catch block is block scoped (this is the only way to achieve bock scoping in ES5, without the use of name analysis).

Comment: Note that `try catch` is pretty likely to make the function it appears in ineligible for optimization, so unless you **really** want that block scoping it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @Pointy, _pretty likely to make the function it appears in ineligible for optimization_ - can you elaborate a bit why?

Comment: @Maximus See [this article on GitHub](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) - it's in section 2.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

> If i create a variable in the catch block, is this block level scope?

If you create a block scoped variable ([using `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)) it is.

> It seems to create it in the global scope.

You are using `var` which always creates the variable in the scope of the current function (or global if you aren't in a function).